# Expand: $e^{\sin z}$ at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need hints to find the Laurent expansion of $\displaystyle e^{\sin z}$ at $z = 0$ in a simpler way. I am getting double series which I can't simplify.

ADDED:: Can it be simpler that the below? I also need to find the radius of convergence.
$$\Large e^{\sin z} = e^{\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\small{B(1, -1/3!, \dots , (-1)^n/(2n+1)!)} z^n}{n!}$$

Comment: I've also added something to my answer about the radius of convergence.  The radius of convergence is the easiest part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Exponential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula).

Supose
$$ f(x)=a_1 x+{a_2 \over 2}x^2+{a_3 \over 6}x^3+\cdots+{a_n \over n!}x^n+\cdots.$$

Then

$$\exp f(x)=e^{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {b_n \over n!}x^n,$$

where

$$b_n=\sum_{\pi=\left\{\,S_1,\,\dots,\,S_k\,\right\}} a_{\left|S_1\right|}\cdots a_{\left|S_k\right|},$$

and the index $\pi$ runs through the list of all partitions $\{S_1,\ldots,S_k\}$ of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. (When $k=0$ the product is empty and so equals $1$.)

We have $a_1=-a_3=a_5=-a_7=\cdots=1$ and $a_2=a_4=a_6=\cdots=0$.

So suppose we want $b_4$.  There are $15$ partitions of $\{1,2,3,4\}$: one corresponding to $1+1+1+1$, six corresponding to $2+1+1$, three corresponding to $2+2$, four corresponding to $3+1$, and one corresponding to $4$.  In this case we can discard the ones containing even numbers, so we need only consider $1+1+1+1$ and $3+1$.  We get
$$
b_4 = a_1^4 + 4a_3 a_1 = 1 - 4 = -3.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
b_0 & & & =1 \\[6pt]
b_1 & = a_1 & & = 1 \\[6pt]
b_2 & = a_1^2 & & = 1 \\[6pt]
b_3 & = a_1^3 + a_3 & & = 1-1 = 0  \\[6pt]
b_4 & = a_1^4 + 4a_3 a_1 & & = 1 - 4 = -3 \\[6pt]
b_5 & = a_1^5 + 10a_3 a_1^2 + a_5 & & = 1 - 10 + 1 = -8 \\[6pt]
b_6 & = a_1^6 + 20 a_3 a_1^3 + 10 a_3^2 + 6a_5 a_1 & & = 6 - 20 + 10 + 1 = -3 \\[6pt]
b_7 & = a_1^7 + 35 a_3 a_1^4 + 70 a_3^2 a_1 + 21a_5 a_1^2 + a_7 & & = 1 - 35 + 70 + 21 - 1 = 56
\end{align}
$$
And so on.

The **radius of convergence** is $\infty$, because this is a composition of two entire functions, and is therefore an entire function.

Comment: could you elaborate it a bit? Using it would give the series in powers of sines, I am looking the power series in $z$

Comment: A power series in $z$ is what the formula gives you.

Comment: I have added above, could you check ...

Comment: I've added some details to the answer.

Comment: I conclude that it was not nice as I expected.

Comment: It's conceivable that there's a simpler expression for the coefficients that somehow arises from the special pattern: that all of the coefficients are $0$ or $\pm1$ and they follow a periodic pattern.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Nice answer (+1), but I think my recursion for the coefficients is easier to use :-)

Comment: @robjohn : Thank you.  As I said, I cannot rule out the possibility that the pattern in the coefficients makes some simplification possible.

Comment: @robjohn : Your answer is very clever (+1) but I don't see that it's easier to use than mine.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: perhaps I am not looking at it right, but I have trouble sorting out the partitions.

Comment: @robjohn : Where you see $a_1^7 + 35 a_3 a_1^4 + 70 a_3^2 a_1 + 21a_5 a_1^2 + a_7$, the first term corresponds to $\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{\text{7 terms}}$, the second to $3+1+1+1+1$, the third to $3+3+1$, and the fourth to $7$.  We include all partitions of the number $7$ that have no even numbers.  Even numbers are excluded because $a_n=0$ whenever $n$ is even.  The coefficient in each case is the corresponding number of partitions of a set of $7$ things.  For example, the number of ways to partition a set of $7$ things as $3+3+1$ is $70$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I understand and know it's correct, but making sure you've not missed any partitions and that you've counted them properly seems harder *to me* than computing $$a_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}a_{n-2k}$$ That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{\sin(x)}=\cos(x)e^{\sin(x)}$. Equating the coefficients for the series on both sides, that is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)a_{k+1}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
$$
we get the following recursion for the coefficients:
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}a_{n-2k}
$$
Since $a_0=1$, we get
$$
e^{\sin(x)}=1+x+\frac12x^2+0x^3-\frac18x^4-\frac1{15}x^5-\frac1{240}x^6+\frac1{90}x^7+\dots
$$
Not working from the sequence of coefficients, but just knowing that the radii of convergence of both $\sin(x)$ and $e^x$ are infinite, the radius of convergence for the composition will also be infinite.

---

**Generalization on the Same Idea**

To get a result similar to the [Exponential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) cited by Michael Hardy, we can use the preceding idea to get a recursion for general $f$. Assuming that $f(0)=0$, and $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_kx^k$
we get the following recursion for $\displaystyle e^{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$:
$$
a_0=1\quad\text{and}\quad a_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)f_{k+1}a_{n-k}
$$

Comment: comparing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ b_n z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ (-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ b_n z^{n}}{n!}$ ??

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: comparing $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)a_{k+1}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$$ yes.